# In Spring Boot 2.5, how do I apply the @CrossOrigin annotation to a specific profile only?

Tags: spring-boot, cors, spring-restcontroller, cross-origin-resource-policy

I'm using SPring Boot 2.5.  I have this at the top of my controller

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", allowedHeaders = "*")
public MyController {
```

This is to allow my local JS application to connect from a different port than what Spring Boot is running on.  However, I don't want this cross origin policy to be in any other environment besides local.  How can I modify the above so that I can apply the @CrossOrigin annotation only to a specific profile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that if you remove the `@CrossOrigin` annotation from the controller and apply the CORS config programmatically using a custom `WebMvcConfigurer` bean which is initialized only for a specific profile. The bean definition would look something like below:

```java
    @Bean
    @Profile("local")
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**")
                        .allowedOrigins("*")
                        .allowedMethods("*")
                        .allowedHeaders("*");
            }
        };
    }
```

The `corsConfigurer` bean will be initialized only when the application is started with the `local` profile, which can be done by setting the value of the `spring.profiles.active` system property or `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE` environment variable to `local`. Something like one of the below commands can be used to start the application with local profile:

```
SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=local java -jar myapp.jar
java -Dspring.profiles.active=local -jar myapp.jar
```

A sample app that uses this cors config can be found on [github](https://github.com/devatherock/spring-boot-demo/tree/cors)

Comment: How is "@Profile("local")" activated?

Comment: When running in local, you would start the app with the JVM arg `spring.profiles.active=local` or with the environment variable `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=local`. When I tested this code, I was using `./gradlew bootrun -Dspring.profiles.active=local`(I do redirect all gradle system properties to the application's java process)

Comment: I updated the answer with sample commands for running the application with the `local` profile

Comment: I tried cutting and pasting the code exactly as you have it -- I can see through debugging that it is getting called during Spring Boot startup, but it is not working.  When I re-add '@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", allowedHeaders = "*")' to my controller, then I am able to connect locally through a different port than what Spring Boot runs on.

Comment: So you are saying the bean is initialized but didn't have an effect? It should - I tested it using the sample app code that I shared in the answer. Can you share the command you are using to start the app with the local profile? And if you can, a minimal app with the `WebMvcConfigurer` bean that reproduces the issue?

Comment: I think I may have identified the issue -- I added your config to a class that already Implemented WebConfigurer (e.g. "implements WebMvcConfigurer").  That class was marked with @Configuration.  So I don't think I can add your config to that class.  I'll update my question with that info.

Comment: Turned out I was importing the wrong library for CorsRegistry.  I guess the proper import is "import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;".